# AWS supervisor spawnerr: can't find command on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, supervisord

Recently I was using digital ocean cloud instance and set up supervisor running like this:

```
[program:programname]
command=/root/programnamefolder/src/programnameexecutable
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
autorestart=true
```

But when I switched to same Ubuntu setup on amazon my supervisor is not able to find command
Im guessing its because of the root settings etc, that are different for amazon instances
Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

```
INFO spawnerr: can't find command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem, instead of root for amazon instance was used ubuntu user, so it was

```
/ubuntu/home/programfolder
```

Hope this helps someone else :)